# How to use Chrome Developer Tools Performance or Memory tab when page freezes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So I've got a page that after it is loaded the Javascript just keeps running and running until I bring up Chrome's Task Manager and kill the tab.

I want to find the memory leak.  When I use the Performance tab and stop a recording it'll say "Loading profile..." forever.  So I'll kill the tab in Task Manager, but then the profile never loads.  Same problem with taking a Heap Snapshot under the Memory Tab.

Is there a way to use the Performance or Memory tabs when I have to kill the tab?
Or do I just have to go "old school" and use console.log() everywhere?

Comment: Try pressing the pause button in devtools Sources panel.

Comment: Ah yes, that worked 